# Getting the child of another parent with jQuery after a selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following (abbreviated) HTML:

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li class="active">C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
        <li>F</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery to move `.active` down the unordered list. When the end of the unordered first list is reached (`C`), I want `.active` to move down to the next `div`, starting at `D`.

How can I use jQuery to select the *first* `li`, *after* the last occurrence of `.active`, *regardless* of who's child it is *without* resorting to (in my opinion) fragile constructs such as `parent().parent()` for example?

Comment: wht jQuery have you tried to reach till end of first unordred list means `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which also handles the movement *within* a single list.

```
var $a = $('.active');
var $n = $a.next('li');

if ($n.length == 0) {
    $n = $a.closest('.content')  // first ancestor matching class
         .next('.content')       // next sibling also matching class
         .find('li').first();    // first <li> descendent therein
}
$a.removeClass('active');
$n.addClass('active');
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Hdy4A/

Comment: @Laurens I've changed the code since you accepted - it's now a bit more efficient

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need

```
var $active = $('li.active');
$active.removeClass('active')
   .next('li')
   .add($active.parents('.content:first')
        .next('.content')
        .find('li:first'))
   .first().addClass('active');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmRBu/4/)

---

**EDIT** Made the code more generic to handle the full flow